# How to stay on same page after login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building an event registration system which displays event registration list if the user is logged in without page refresh using Ajax. However, when I try to login I get undefined index name on line `echo "Hello ".$_SESSION["name"]."<br/>";` in index.php. My code is:-
 index.php:-

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once('dbconnect.php');
require_once('function.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Registration</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <!--Login div-->
        <div id="logincontainer"> 
            <form id="loginform" method="post">

                <h3>Login</h3>
                <div class="display-error" style="display: none;"></div>
                <input type="email" name="lemail" placeholder="Enter email address" required>

                <input type="password" name="lpassword" placeholder="Enter password" required>

                <input type="submit" value="Sign In">

                <p><a href="forgotpassword.php">Forgot Password</a></p>

                <p id="bottom">Don't have an account yet? <a href="#" id="signup">Sign up</a></p>

            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="signupcontainer">
            <form id="registerform" method="post">
                <h3>Register</h3>
                <div class="display-error" style="display: none;"></div>
                <input type="text" name="rname" placeholder="Full Name" required>

                <input type="email" name="remail" placeholder="Enter valid email" required>

                <input type="password" name="rpassword" placeholder="Password" required>

                <input type="text" name="rmobile" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" placeholder="Mobile" required>

                <input type="submit" value="Create Account">

                <p id="bottom">Already have an account? <a href="#" id="signin">Sign In</a></p>

            </form>


        </div>

        <!--Testing refresh portion-->
        <div id="after-login" style="display: none;">
            <?php
                echo "Hello ".$_SESSION["name"]."<br/>";
                echo '<a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-logout"></span>Sign Out</a><br/>';
            ?>
            <form id="events" method="post">
                Code Ardor<input type="checkbox" name="coding[]" value="ardor"> &nbsp;
                Designophy<input type="checkbox" name="coding[]" value="design"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit-btn">
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--Testing portion ends-->

    </div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loginform").submit(function(){
                var data = $("#loginform").serialize();
                checkRecords(data);
                return false;
            });
            function checkRecords(data){

                $.ajax({
                    url : 'loginprocess.php',
                    data : data,
                    type : 'POST',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.code == 200){
                            //alert('You have successfully logged in');
                            //window.location='dashboard.php';
                            $("#logincontainer").hide();
                            $("#after-login").show();
                        }
                        else{
                            $(".display-error").html("<ul>"+data.msg+"</ul");
                            $(".display-error").css("display","block");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("Email/Password is Incorrect");
                }
                }); 
            }
        });

    </script>
    <!--Signup Ajax-->
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#registerform").submit(function(){
                var data = $("#registerform").serialize();
                signupRecords(data);
                return false;
            });
            function signupRecords(data){

                $.ajax({
                    url : 'signupprocess.php',
                    data : data,
                    type : 'POST',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.code == 200){
                            alert('You have successfully Signed Up \n Please Login now.');
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                location.reload();
                            },500);
                        }
                        else{
                            $(".display-error").html("<ul>"+data.msg+"</ul");
                            $(".display-error").css("display","block");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR,exception){
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                }
                }); 
            }
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

loginprocess.php

```
    <?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once('dbconnect.php');
require_once('function.php');
$errorMsg = "";
$email = trim($_POST["lemail"]);
$password = trim($_POST["lpassword"]);

if(empty($email)){
    $errorMsg .= "<li>Email is required</li>";
}
else{
    $email = filterEmail($email);
    if($email == FALSE){
        $errorMsg .= "<li>Invalid Email Format</li>";
    }
}

if(empty($password)){
    $errorMsg .= "<li>Password Required.</li>";
}
else{
    $password = $password;
}

if(empty($errorMsg)){
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT password from users WHERE email = ?");
    $query->execute(array($email));
    $pwd = $query->fetchColumn();
    if(password_verify($password, $pwd)){
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        //Testing piece
        $qry = $db->prepare("SELECT name from users WHERE email = ?");
        $qry->execute(array($email));
        $nme = $qry->fetchColumn();
        $_SESSION['name']=$nme;
        //Testing code ends
        echo json_encode(['code'=>200, 'email'=>$_SESSION['email']]);
        exit;
    }
    else{
        json_encode(['code'=>400, 'msg'=>'Invalid Email/Password']);
        exit;
    }
}
else{
    echo json_encode(['code'=>404, 'msg'=>$errorMsg]);
}

?>
```

Comment: Try adding `header("Location:" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` in your "success" code.

Edit: scrap that. It wasn't what you were after. My bad.

Comment: You need to do a page refresh after the login to generate the PHP variables. So you might as well do a normal login and no ajax. Use the page url in the action of the login form.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the problem is that after login call you DO NOT reload the `#after-login` container contents - you only show it.

```
if(data.code == 200){
  //alert('You have successfully logged in');
  //window.location='dashboard.php';
  $("#logincontainer").hide();
  $("#after-login").show();
}
```

In the other words the `#after-login` contents only load on the first page load (before login) and then are not updated by your ajax call (only then you would have access to `$_SESSION["name"]`).

IMHO proper solution would be to return the `$_SESSION["name"]` value in the `loginprocess.php` response and update it in the `#after-login` container before showing it (eg. use an empty span where the name should appear which you'll fill out on login).

```
//Something like
if(data.code == 200){
  //alert('You have successfully logged in');
  //window.location='dashboard.php';
  $("span#name_placeholder").text(data.name) //return name from loginprocess.php
  $("#logincontainer").hide();
  $("#after-login").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would to be to create a html element like this  for the

```
<div id="after-login" style="display: none;">
           <h5 id="Username"></h5>
            <?php

                echo '<a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-logout"></span>Sign Out</a><br/>';
            ?>
            <form id="events" method="post">
                Code Ardor<input type="checkbox" name="coding[]" value="ardor"> &nbsp;
                Designophy<input type="checkbox" name="coding[]" value="design"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit-btn">
            </form>
        </div>
```

then after this include the username in the json like this

```
 $qry = $db->prepare("SELECT name from users WHERE email = ?");
            $qry->execute(array($email));
            $nme = $qry->fetchColumn();
            //$_SESSION['name']=$nme;
            //Testing code ends
            echo json_encode(['code'=>200, 'email'=>$_SESSION['email'],'username'=>$nme]);
            exit;
```

on the ajax call you can now access the json response with the username included and feed the span element with the username like this

```
    if(data.code == 200){
                                //alert('You have successfully logged in');
                                //window.location='dashboard.php';
                                $("#username").test(data.username);
                                $("#logincontainer").hide();
                                $("#after-login").show();
                            }
```

Comment: Your solution works but was curious as for how to set the session since I will need the session to update the entries in the database with the values of the events form or is there another way to update the database?